# Secure RabbitMQ with MQTT plugin on Docker

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am running RabbitMQ on Docker with the MQTT plugin.
My Docker file is:

```
FROM rabbitmq

RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_management
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_mqtt

EXPOSE 15671 15672
EXPOSE 1883
```

How can I secure the connection to the MQTT plugin?
For example for authentication, the MQTT adapter can be configured to use user name/pass using `allow_anonymous`

How to change the RabbitMQ docker image configuration?

Thanks!